# Variance of conditional mean estimates obtained from a mixed model/multilevel model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-intercepts

Assuming I have observations nested in groups with varying (true) means. Using a random intercepts mixed model (multilevel model), I can estimate the variance of these random intercepts. Additionally, I could estimate the group means, conditional on the model. Is it reasonable to expect that variance of conditional mean estimates obtained from a mixed model is equal to the estimated variance of a random intercept?

I can provide some code to simulate data using R:

```
intcp_var <- 9

intcp <- MASS::mvrnorm(100, mu = 10, Sigma = 9, empirical = TRUE)

dat <- lapply(intcp, FUN = function(intc){
  rnorm(100, mean = intc, sd = 5)
})

df <- data.frame(y = unlist(dat),
                 group = rep(1:100, each = 100))
```

This code should simulate observations from 100 groups, each with n = 100. Across the 100 groups, the true means have a variance of 9.

We can use lme4 to model the observations using a random intercepts mixed model (multilevel model). Using lme4::fixef(fit) and lme4::ranef(fit), we can obtain estimates of the conditional group means:

```
fit <- lme4::lmer(y ~ 1 | group, data = df)

cond_means <- lme4::fixef(fit) + unlist(lme4::ranef(fit)$group)
```

Now, usually I would have expected the standard deviation/variance of those estimated conditional means to be identical to the estimates standard deviation/variance of the random intercepts in the model.

```
sd(cond_means)

as.data.frame(lme4::VarCorr(fit))$sdcor[1]

fit
```

However, this seems to not be the case. In this case, the deviation is rather small. I'm working with more complex situations, where the difference is much more noticeable. So I'm wondering, whether my inital assumption that these should be identical was unreasonable - perhaps the estimation of conditional means does not "force" their variance/sd to be perfectly identical to our model's estimates?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Your intuition for how lme4 fits GLMs is not quite right. You can learn more about this in Ch. 5, Computational Methods for Mixed Models, of [lme4: Mixed-effects modeling with R](https://stat.ethz.ch/~maechler/MEMo-pages/lMMwR.pdf) by D. Bates.

Comment: A couple of details that you may want to consider: (a) `lme4::lmer` has two estimation criteria, REML and ML. You are using the default which is REML. (b) The random effect estimates -- ie. `re = lme4::ranef(fit)$group` -- are constrained to have mean zero. So I think you shouldn't use `var(re)` or `sd(re)` to compute the variance/std. dev. of the estimated random effects. Use instead `sum(re^2) / n_re` where `n_re` is the number of random effect levels (here `n_re` = 100).

Comment: @dipetkov Thanks for your input! While I'm still looking into Ch.5 of the Bates-book, let me refer to the details a) and b) you mentioned.
To a) - even switching to the ML-estimator seems to not change anything here. 
To b) - I see how using var() or sd() implies that I am trying to estimate the population-parameters of the random effects. However, using the observed sample variance/standard deviation 'sum(re^2) / n_re' still lead to differences (no matter whether ML or REML was used).
I assume those details to be irrelevant, respective my incorrect intuition though :D